# How to use segues

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating an app in Xcode that currently consist of a Navigation Controller a Table View Controller and a regular View Controller.

I'm using StoryBoard and have created a segue between the table view and the regular view controller. In the navigation bar I have a button that I've dragged to the view controller in the StoryBoard. When I click at the button, the new View Controller is viewed like it suppose to. I then tried to pass data from the table view controller, see below:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"läggTill"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        AddPlayerViewController *apv = [segue destinationViewController];

        [apv.myTextField setText:@"hello"];

    }

}
```

The segue identifier is "läggTill", but the code inside the if-statement is not executing.

Two questions:

What is wrong with this approach?

Is this the best approach when using StoryBoards? Can I pass data via viewWillDisappear?

Can I use segues to pass data back to the table view controller from the view controller?

Comment: Can you try change the segue identifier to use just english characters in your code and in storyboard.

Comment: The segue identifier in the Storyboard have the same name?

Comment: Can I use segues to pass data back to the table view controller from the view controller? Use a Delegate to do that.

Comment: Is your myTextField on the AddPlayerViewController? In the code you've posted you are getting a reference to the destination view controller and calling it apv but setting myTextField on avc? Is this just a typo or is it setting something entirely different?

Comment: Well, I changed the code example here. I'm using the right one in my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes all the sense in the world to pass your data in the `prepareForSegue:sender:`. I would not recommend passing data in `viewWillDisappear` because it just makes it messy and it reduces readability + it becomes harder to keep track.

I think your string comparison is not working! Put an NSLog for your identifier string see on the console. I have a feeling it might not like the "ä" character in comparison.

About your last question, as Gabriel.Massana pointed out, for passing data back, using delegate is the way to go.

**Note 1:** Another problem I noticed is a possible typo you might have "apv" and "avc".

**Note 2:** Another reason for it failing is that you are setting the TextField before `viewDidLoad` gets called on your destination controller. I suggest that pass it as string and in the `viewDidLoad` of your destination,  set the text to your TextField.

Comment: @iHank In your storyboard click on your segue and double check the identifier. See if it matches with your string.

Comment: Thanks, this post was very useful! Seems like I namned the segue "läggTIll", not "läggTill". I saw it when I used the NSLog.